# Google Kick Start: Metal Harvest Wrong Solution

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to practice for Google Kick Start and to solve the [Metal Harvest Task](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff48/00000000003f4b8b#problem):

> You are in charge of deploying robots to harvest Kickium from a nearby asteroid. Robots are not designed to work as a team, so only one robot can harvest at any point of time. A single robot can be deployed for up to K units of time in a row before it returns for calibration, regardless of how much time it spends on harvesting during that period. Harvesting can only be done during specific time intervals. These time intervals do not overlap. Given K and the time intervals in which harvesting is allowed, what is the minimum number of robot deployments required to harvest at all possible times?

I read the analysis and I get it, but I don't get why my solution doesn't work. I always get "WA" - wrong answer, when submitting it.

The main idea is that I first sort the intervals, then group them into chunks, where there's less than K time steps between all intervals in a chunk. Within a chunk, I then deploy robots continuously every K steps, ie, requiring `math.ceil(chunk_len / K)` robots per chunk. I don't need robots between chunks.

That makes sense conceptually, right? It also passes my test cases.
So I'm guessing, I have some mistake regarding list indices or edge cases, but I can't figure out what.

```py
import math


class Interval:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end


class Solution:
    def __init__(self, max_time, intervals):
        self.max_time = max_time
        self.intervals = intervals

    def harvest_v1(self):
        """start harvesting and return min number of robots"""
        num_robots = 0

        # sort intervals with increasing start time --> O(N log(N))
        sorted_intervals = sorted(self.intervals, key=lambda interval: interval.start)

        # walk through intervals, starting at  --> O(N)
        chunk_start = sorted_intervals[0].start
        for i in range(1, len(sorted_intervals)):
            # calc duration to next interval and stop chunk if there's K or more time until the next interval
            time_to_next = sorted_intervals[i].start - sorted_intervals[i-1].end
            if time_to_next >= self.max_time:
                # then stop chunk and compute num robots needed for chunk
                chunk_len = sorted_intervals[i-1].end - chunk_start
                num_robots += math.ceil(chunk_len / self.max_time)
                # start a new chunk
                chunk_start = sorted_intervals[i].start

        # then still include last interval
        chunk_len = sorted_intervals[-1].end - chunk_start
        num_robots += math.ceil(chunk_len / self.max_time)

        return num_robots


# read input and generate output
num_tests = int(input())
for test in range(1, num_tests + 1):
    num_intervals, max_time = [int(k) for k in input().split()]
    intervals = []
    for interval in range(num_intervals):
        start, end = [int(k) for k in input().split()]
        intervals.append(Interval(start, end))

    sol = Solution(max_time, intervals)
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(test, sol.harvest_v1()))
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: i think your missing cases where interval_size > max time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach, probably, will work for most of the test cases, but there are some corner cases that will prove it wrong.
Try this test case, you'll understand why it fails:

```
    max_time = 6
    intervals = [Interval(1,3), Interval(4,7), Interval(11,16), Interval(17,22)]
```

> Correct Output : 3

> Your program's output: 4

**Explanation**

Your code marks `chunk start = start of the first interval` and loops forward until it finds an interval with time gap from its previous interval `>= max_time`. It calculates the `robot deployments` required till that interval using the `chunk start` and `end time` of the current interval in loop. Since your code only handles `time_to_next >= self.max_time` condition, its opposite condition becomes a problem.

In the test case I mentioned earlier, your code will fit all the intervals into a single chunk, because time gap between all the intervals is lesser than `max_time`, but optimal solution would be to do it in 2 or 3 chunks.

---

In case you want to try a different approach, then have a look at this code:

```
def harvest_v1(self):
    sorted_intervals = sorted(self.intervals, key=lambda interval: interval.start)
    robots_deployed = 0         # Keeps track of total robots deployed
    next_calibration_time = 0   # Keeps track of time for next robot calibration

    for interval in sorted_intervals:
        start_i = interval.start
        end_i = interval.end
        interval_duration = end_i - start_i

        if next_calibration_time <= start_i:    # If no robot has been deployed yet 
                                                # or previous robot has been sent for calibration, then
            
            # calculate the number of deployments required for current interval
            deployments_required = math.ceil(interval_duration / self.max_time)
            robots_deployed += deployments_required

            # calculate and track the time at which lastly deployed robot will be sent for calibration
            next_calibration_time = start_i + (deployments_required * self.max_time)

        elif next_calibration_time < end_i:     # If some robot is still working then

            # calculate the time remaining in current interval after currently working robot becomes unavailable
            remaining_duration = end_i - next_calibration_time

            # calculate the number of deployments required
            deployments_required = math.ceil(remaining_duration / self.max_time)
            robots_deployed += deployments_required

            # calculate and track the time at which lastly deployed robot will be sent for calibration
            next_calibration_time = next_calibration_time + (deployments_required * self.max_time)

    return robots_deployed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now understand that there are cases where intervals are closer than K steps together but should still be split into separate chunks, which is where my approach returns the wrong answer.

Comment: However, in your example, my code works fine and returns the correct solution (4). An even simpler example that fails is: K=6 and 2 intervals [1,7] and [8,14]. Both intervals are exactly 6 steps long, so a single robot per interval (2 in total) would suffice. But since the gap between the intervals is 1<K=6, my approach would group them into one chunk of length 13 and send `math.ceil(13/6)=3` robots.

Comment: Ah, I see. In the previous example, the correct solution was 3, not 4 and my approach gets it wrong. Answer accepted :)

Comment: My test case answers were not right before, I fixed it now. But you won't need it now, your test case is simpler to understand.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer :) I am glad that I could help.